# Unable to send binary data over WebSockets

Tags: c++, websocket, server-push

I am developing a viewer application, in which server captures image, perform some image processing operations and this needs to be shown at the client end, on HTML5 canvas. The server that I've written is in VC++ and uses http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371188/A-Cplusplus-Websocket-server-for-realtime-interact.

So far I've implemented the needed functionality. Now all I need to do is Optimization. Reference was a chat application which was meant to send strings, and so I was encoding data into 7-bit format. Which is causing overhead. I need binary data transfer capability. So I modified the encoding and framing (Now opcode is 130, for binary messages instead of 129.) and I can say that server part is alright. I've observed the outgoing frame, it follows protocol. I'm facing problem in the client side.

Whenever the client receives the incoming message, if all the bytes are within limits (0 to 127) it calls onMessage() and I can successfully decode the incoming message. However even a single introduction of character which is >127 causes the client to call onClose(). The connection gets closed and I am unable to find cause. Please help me out.

PS: I'm using chrome 22.0 and Firefox 17.0

Comment: I am facing same problem. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is related to how you assemble  your frames?  As you have an established connection that terminates when the onmessage event is about to fire, i asume that it is frame related?

What if you study the network -> WebSocket -> frame of your connection i Google Chrome?  what does it say?

it may be out-of-scope for you ?, but im one of the developers of XSockets.NET (C#) framework, we have binary support there, if you are interested there is an example that i happend to publish just recently, it can be found on https://github.com/MagnusThor/XSockets.Binary.Controller.Example

Comment: Actually I don't think so. The code was written for transmitting text frames.
One packet takes 8kB. If I encode it utilizing only 7bits only, (no byte can be above 0x7F) everything runs as expected. I just make one change while sending binary data i.e. I change the Opcode from 0x01 (text frame) to 0x02 (binary frame).
At client side for the sake of testing I'm just writing an alert in my OnMessage(). And in case of binary message the OnMessage never gets called. It goes to the socket.OnClose() and closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

How did you observe the outgoing frame and what were the header bytes that you observed? It sounds like you may not actually be setting the binary opcode successfully, and this is triggering UTF-8 validation in the browser which fails.

Comment: I observed it by stepping in Visual Studio, when the data was being framed. I'll try to add the exact frame data sequence here soon, so it'll be helpful to debug.

Comment: You might try capturing using wireshark so that you can see the actual data on the wire.